# run single integration test with gradle

Tags: testing, integration, gradle

I'm trying to run a single integration tests using gradle's `-Dtest.single` flag. I have added another source set, `src/integrationTest` and put the tests in there. I have an integration test task

```groovy
task integrationTests(type: Test) {
    dependsOn 'assemble', 'integrationTestClasses'    
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

This runs fine, but if I try to run a single test it tells me it cannot find a matching test. I don't want to have to run every integration test each time I am writing a new one. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

`gradle testTaskName -DtestTaskName.single=...`

In this case:

`gradle integrationTest -DintegrationTest.single=...`

Comment: When I try this, I get something like:

`$ gradlew -Dtest.single=SingleTest :subproject:test 
... 
:buildSrc:test FAILED 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':test'.
Could not find matching test for pattern: SingleTest`

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a test class with that name?

Comment: I found that -Dtest.single='foo'  was ok on linux but failed on win due to the use of ' vs "  or nothing.   So, those choices may have impacts due to the shell used.

Comment: Actually, it should be `-DintegrationTest.single=...` (without the "s")

Comment: Actually it should be -DintegrationTests.single=... because he named the task 'integrationTests' in his gradle file.

Answer (score 43):

Since Gradle 1.10 you can write:

```
 //select specific test method
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest.someFeature

//select specific test class
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest

//select all tests from package
gradle test --tests org.gradle.internal*

//select all ui test methods from integration tests by naming convention
gradle test --tests *IntegTest*ui*

//selecting tests from different test tasks
gradle test --tests *UiTest integTest --tests *WebTest*ui
```

Read more here 
http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.10/release-notes#executing-specific-tests-from-the-command-line

Comment: The embedded link nor comment mentions if this works for the integrationTest that the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Just incase anyone is coming here looking for answers. This has been removed in gradle 5.0. Look for `test.single` in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

If you still wish to use a command line option in this style you should be able to use the `--tests` commandline param. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#simple_name_pattern

```
$ ./gradlew integrationTest --tests=MyTest
```